# Show next Wednesday every 2 weeks PHP

Tags: php, date

For an e-commerce store, we're trying to show the next date we will be ordering new stock. We order stock every other Wednesday.
At the moment I have this:

```
<?php
$number_of_dates = 1;
$startDate = mktime(0, 0, 0, 6, 4, 2020); // May 2, 2012
for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_dates; $i++) {
   $date = strtotime('Wednesday +' . ($i * 2) . ' weeks', $startDate);
   echo date('d-m-Y', $date).PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

The problem with this is, from testing, it doesn't show the next date. So when it will continue showing the first date from the start date and won't move on to the next.

Comment: Would it be because you set $number_of_dates to 1?

Answer (score 3):

Working with dates is easier using the `DateTime()` family of classes.

I *think* this does what you are looking for. You may need to tweak it to suit your specific needs.

```
$today = new DateTimeImmutable('next Wednesday');
$end = $today->modify('+4 weeks');
$interval = new DateInterval('P2W');
$period = new DatePeriod($today, $interval, $end);
foreach ($period as $date) {
    printf('%s%s', $date->format('Y-m-d'), PHP_EOL);
}
```

Outputs

```
2020-06-10
2020-06-24
```